# lmbench3 cross-compiling undefined pmap_set

Tags: linux, makefile, cross-compiling, rpc

I would like to cross-compile lmbench for ARM64, on a x86 machine. I have built my own cross-compiler according to the guide here:  http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

When I tried cross-compiling lmbench3 with this cross-compiler I first had to:

1. remove all the lines where bk.ver was used in the src/Makefile
2. replace bk.ver by 3 at line 200 of the Makefile, so that I have:

---

```
sed -e "s/<version>/3/g" < ../scripts/lmbench > $O/lmbench
```

3. Set `CC=aarch64-linux-gcc`, `OS=aarch64-linux-gnu`, `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -static"`
4. Put all the `glibc-2.20/sunrpc/rpc` header files into `/opt/cross/aarch64-linux/include/rpc` folder
5. Then when I type the make command I get the following error:

---

```
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/florian/lmbench3/src'
aarch64-linux-gcc -O -DRUSAGE -DHAVE_uint=1 -DHAVE_int64_t=1 -DHAVE_DRAND48 -DHAVE_SCHED_SETAFFINITY=1   -o ../bin/aarch64-linux-gnu/bw_tcp bw_tcp.c ../bin/aarch64-linux-gnu/lmbench.a -lm
../bin/aarch64-linux-gnu/lmbench.a(lib_tcp.o): In function `tcp_done':
lib_tcp.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `pmap_unset'
../bin/aarch64-linux-gnu/lmbench.a(lib_tcp.o): In function `tcp_connect':
lib_tcp.c:(.text+0x338): undefined reference to `pmap_getport'
../bin/aarch64-linux-gnu/lmbench.a(lib_tcp.o): In function `tcp_server':
lib_tcp.c:(.text+0x568): undefined reference to `pmap_unset'
lib_tcp.c:(.text+0x584): undefined reference to `pmap_set'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [../bin/aarch64-linux-gnu/bw_tcp] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/florian/lmbench3/src'
make: *** [lmbench] Error 2
```

I know that `pmap_set`, `pmap_unset` and `pmap_getport` are called in `lib_tcp.c`, but I don't find anywhere their definitions. When I compile lmbench3 for x86 I don't get this error, and I checked everywhere on the host machine for the definition of these functions, but still don't find them anywhere.

Does anyone know what to do with this error? I guess I still need to use RPC, so I'd prefer not commenting any line.

Comment: What is your ARM target, what OS it has? Does this OS have xdr library? (pmap_set man page http://linux.die.net/man/3/pmap_set has link to xdr man page.) Do you have arm's xdr library in your cross system?

Comment: the target OS is Linux. I have to check whether xdr library is in the cross system. But basically i used the same version of gcc, binutils, mfpg, etc... as done in the link provided in my original post for build the cross compiler from source.

Comment: pmap are defined in glibc (include/rpc/pmap_clnt.h https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/846d9a4a3acdb4939ca7bf6aed48f9f6f26911be/include/rpc/pmap_clnt.h & sunrpc/pmap_clnt.c https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/846d9a4a3acdb4939ca7bf6aed48f9f6f26911be/sunrpc/pmap_clnt.c), but were this part of library configured and built? You should check buildlog. The functions may be defined in other object. Can you post output of failed command with `-v` and `-Wl,--verbose`  options added `aarch64-linux-gcc -v ..` / `aarch64-linux-gcc -Wl,--verbose ...`?

Answer (score 2):

From the error info, ld didn't find the lib, try following

```
make results LDFLAGS=-ltirpc
```